# Join with comma separated values using LINQ to SQL in .NET Core (EF Core) without direct relation between tables

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table [CourseMaster] LIKE

```
CourseId    CourseName
-----------------------
  01          ABC
  02          DEF
  03          GHI
  04          JKL
  05          MNO
  06          PQR
  07          STU
```

And I have another table [StudentMaster] for Student Details LIKE

```
ROLLNO  NAME    ADDRESS       
------------------------------
12345   RAM     RAM ADDRESS                     
25695   HARI    HARI ADDRESS                   
89685   JEFF    JEFF ADDRESS              
47896   DAISY   DAISY ADDRESS
```

And I have another table [StudentCourseMaster] for Student Course Details LIKE

```
ROLLNO     CourseId      
-------------------
12345      01             
12345      02                 
12345      06            
25695      02
25695      06
89685      03
89685      05
89685      06
89685      07
47896      03
```

I am trying to fetch the record in below format using LINQ to SQL query.

```
ROLLNO  NAME    ADDRESS         Course
-------------------------------------------
12345   RAM     RAM ADDRESS     ABC,DEF,PQR                   
25695   HARI    HARI ADDRESS    DEF,PQR                       
89685   JEFF    JEFF ADDRESS    GHI,MNO,PQR,STU               
47896   DAISY   DAISY ADDRESS   GHI
```

Here is my Linq to SQL query

```
from student in _context.StudentMaster
            select new StudentDto
            {
                RollNo = student.RollNo,
                Name = student.Name,
                Address = student.Address,
                Courses = String.Join(", ", (from courseMapping in _context.StudentCourseMaster.Include(x => x.CourseMaster)
                                             where courseMapping.RollNo == student.RollNo
                                             select courseMapping.CourseMaster.CourseName)),
            }
```

I am getting this error[image]

My Concerns:

1. Is there other way around writing this query?
2. If I want to filter students based on Course IDs, how should I include that?

Thank you and any valuable suggestion will be highly appreciate.

Comment: Can you post Classes? It is important to know which navigation properties do you have.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks for highlighting that part, I did some digging and found few things. And sorry but I can't share these classes.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the navigation property:

```
from student in _context.StudentMasters
select new StudentDto
{
    RollNo = student.RollNo,
    Name = student.Name,
    Address = student.Address,
    Courses = string.Join(", ", student.CourseMasters.Select(x => x.CourseName))
}
```

Comment: @alexander-petrow this will include all courses, I just need the specific ones.

Comment: I tried joining the tables, but now getting error `The query has been configured to use 'QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery' and contains a collection in the 'Select' call, which could not be split into separate query. Please remove 'AsSplitQuery' if applied or add 'AsSingleQuery' to the query.'`

Comment: Update to EF Core 6. Or disable this warning. Or use `AsSingleQuery()`